# Why is it necessary to validate data in a servlet obtained by calling HttpSession.getAttribute()?

Tags: java, security

I am new to WebApp programming and am trying to understand the security implications of not validating data obtained by calling the `javax.servlet.http.HttpSession.getAttribute()` interface method. I am using a security code scanner that has flagged this potential vulnerability.

I know that as a general rule I should always validate data obtained from a non-trusted source, but I guess I don't understand why the contents of the session would be untrusted. This is based on my (probably unwarranted) assumptions that the only way data could be added to the session would be by calling `HttpSession.setAttribute()` and that only trusted code that is within the scope of the same application should be able to do that.

I guess what I am really asking is how an attacker would exploit an application that failed validate data obtain from the HttpSession. Is it because the implementation is unknown and it cannot be guaranteed that the contents of the session are not constructed somehow from data in the HTTP request (aside from a session id) and thus are subject to tampering? Or is it because trusting the contents of session means implicitly trusting the session id, which may be compromised and point to the wrong session? (although for that to happen it seems like the attacker would have to have some means of creating an alternate session that contains the compromised data).

Assuming that the contents of the session is not constructed from data in the request, is it the case that the only way this vulnerability could be exploited is if there is another vulnerability that would allow an attacker to create a bad session? E.g. uploading executable code and getting the server to execute it and return a session id that is captured and replayed?

Thx

Comment: Which security code scanner is this?

Comment: How are you suppose to validate this data? Is this scanner advising something?

Answer (score 0):

I think all it's saying is that with a user probably entering the data you can't be sure what the user entered or that there was any kind of client-side validation.  If you blindly invoke function based on what you receive in the request then you might have a security problem.  For example, before retrieving customer information for a user-entered customer ID, make sure the ID is valid and make sure the user has the authority to see the data.

Comment: But the data in the HttpSession is *not* data that was received in the request. (It could indirectly come from the user, but in that case it should have been validated before putting it in, not when taking it out of the session)

Comment: The point is still that the scanner appears to be saying you can't trust the data because it might have been entered by the user/client at one time.  I think it's overblown and overkill, but that's what security folks think about all the time.

Comment: 'security folks' care about having clear boundaries between which values are trusted (and what that means), and which are not. Validating the values before they're put into the session *and* after they're taken out of the session is actually bad practice, because it makes it less clear whether or not it should be assumed (and thus enforced) that values in the session have been validated.

Comment: @ArnoutEngelen: absolutely agree.  but I'm not a security person.  that's why they have security people.

Answer (score 0):

Data can be added to the session from the form too. The request may come from another servlet/application and not necessarily from a form. It is easy for someone to set SQL statements for SQL injection in a form/servlet and forward it to the servlet. This is just a possibility that I can think of.
Having said that, I don't recall validating session attribute...ever!

Comment: How can data be added to the session from the form? Wouldn't that at least be framework-specific? Or is there something in the servlet spec that allows this?

Comment: `session.setAttribute("variablename",value);`
You can do this in a JSP.
Also,I can submit to a sevlet from the form and in the servlet add the attribute to the session before I forward to the servlet where there is no validation.

Comment: OK, I interpreted 'from the form' to mean 'from the client side'. Indeed any serverside code (such as a JSP or servlet) can put stuff in the session.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to validate data in the HttpSession as long as you don't put anything into HttpSession that you don't trust.  The HttpSession is created for your webapp, when you ask it to be, and should only contain things you have added to it in one of your servlets or JSPs - though possibly indirectly if you are using some additional framework.

I would personally make sure I never put anything in HttpSession that I was going to have to validate again later when I took it out.  In a simple servlet container environment it is only going to be your own code that updates the session (except when the container automatically removes it, if it times out).

Unless you are using a framework that adds things into the HttpSession automatically *and* those things might have come straight from the user without being sanitized, then you should be okay.  If your own code is currently putting things in HttpSession you don't trust, I'd change it to not do that.

Note that JSPs make no difference in this regard; JSPs *are* servlets once they are compiled.  If you trust what your servlets put into the HttpSession you should be able to trust what your JSPs do with it too.  (They are, after all, *your* JSPs.)

Re 'Is it because the implementation is unknown and it cannot be guaranteed that the contents of the session are not constructed somehow from data in the HTTP request (aside from a session id) and thus are subject to tampering?'.  There is nothing in the servlet specification what would either mandate or allow this to happen.  So no, this is not the reason.

Re 'Or is it because trusting the contents of session means implicitly trusting the session id, which may be compromised and point to the wrong session?'  I'm not sure about 'the wrong session'.  However, once someone (other than the intend user) has the session id (JSESSIONID) they essentially *are* the intended user, and can do anything that user can do (within the capabilities of the webapp in question).  This is true whether the compromised data is coming from the session, a database, or whatever.

A common servlet/MVC/JSP approach is to log the user in (by whatever means) and at that time create the user a HttpSession containing a minimal representation of that user (for example, a UserLogin POJO containing user id, name, etc, etc).  From then on the webapp trusts that this information is valid and uses it identify the user - e.g. a HTTP request arrives with JSESSIONID, which maps to a HttpSession, which maps to some data in the session (UserLogin POJO), which then identifies the requesting user when making calls to the underlying system from within the webapp (e.g. making database calls).  Absence of the HttpSession and UserLogin session data then indicates that the user is not logged in.  This is very common in webapps and depends in being able to trust the JSESSIONID and the HttpSession it maps to.  (The important thing is that the JSESSIONID is a temporary token used by the system to represent the user for this session only; whereas a user USER_ID [in a SQL database, for example] will generally be permanent and not revocable, and hence should not be used to identify the logged in user that made a request.)

By the way (since someone mentioned JSPs above) I wouldn't write a webapp where JSPs touched the session - I would limit the JSPs to rendering the data that was provided to them by an MVC-based servlet.

(I also wouldn't use JSPs at all if I had a choice: JSPs are fairly clunky, the syntax is ugly and there are a number of other limitations - try using JSP to template an email, rather than a HTML page, for example, without jumping through a bunch of hoops.  Considered using Velocity or similar.)